# React-Native: tabLongPress event listener on react-navigation bottom tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I'm using `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` and it works great!
How can I add the listener for the long press event on tab icons?

```
<Tab.Navigator ...>
  <Tab.Screen
    ...
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={icon}
          color={color}
          size={24}
        />
      ),
    }}
    listeners={{
      tabPress: () => console.log('tabPress')
    }}
  />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

I tried the following ways to resolve this issue but none works.

- Wrap FontAwesomeIcon with gesture handler
- Add `tabLongPress` listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tab.Navigator` now has `onTabLongPress` option.

```
<Tab.Navigator
  onTabLongPress={handleTabLongPress}
>
```

My package.json

```
{
  ...
  "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.4",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all prevent default behavior

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('tabPress', (e) => {
 // Prevent default behavior

 e.preventDefault();
 // Do something manually
 });

 return unsubscribe;
}, [navigation]);
```

Comment: I don't think this is an answer to my question. I'm looking for a solution to add a listener for the long press event on tab icons, not the press event.